# Docker image doesn't run when tomcat and postgres are combined

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, tomcat, dockerfile

I have my war file and Dockerfile ready, now I want to create an environment which has ubuntu:16.04 as container OS and java, tomcat, Postgres to be installed. The image builds successfully, but when I run the container, I'm getting an error

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"/usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh\": stat /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: permission denied": unknown.
```

I have removed the postgres instructions, then tomcat is running fine.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
#tomcat and java
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get install nano
RUN apt-get -y install openjdk-8-jdk wget
RUN mkdir /usr/local/tomcat
RUN wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.22/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.22.tar.gz -O /tmp/tomcat.tar.gz
RUN cd /tmp && tar xvfz tomcat.tar.gz
RUN cp -Rv /tmp/apache-tomcat-9.0.22/ /usr/local/tomcat/
ADD tomcat-users.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/
ADD context.xml /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager/META-INF/

ADD myapp.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["/usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh", "run"]

#postgres
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install wget
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade
RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ xenial-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list


RUN wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add -

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN apt-get install -y postgresql-10
RUN apt-get install -y postgresql-client-10
RUN apt-get install -y postgresql-contrib-10

USER postgres
RUN /etc/init.d/postgresql start &&\
    psql --command "CREATE USER postgresondocker WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'postgresondocker';" &&\
    createdb -O postgresondocker postgresondocker
RUN echo "host all  all    0.0.0.0/0  md5" >> /etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf
RUN echo "listen_addresses='*'" >> /etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf
EXPOSE 5432
VOLUME  ["/etc/postgresql", "/var/log/postgresql", "/var/lib/postgresql"]

# Set the default command to run when starting the container
#CMD ["/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/postgres", "-D", "/var/lib/postgresql/10/main", "-c", "config_file=/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf"]
```

If I comment the postgres installation starting with #postgres, then tomcat is running fine.
Also, the #CMD for postgres is different from tomcat, I have read that I cannot use two CMD instructions as the last one will be executed. How can I combine both CMD instructions of tomcat and postgres.

Comment: Don't put both Tomcat and Postgresql in the same image or the same container. Have a separate image for each, and run two containers. You can use docker-compose or such to manage them together.

Comment: You should almost always run this as two separate containers.  The Docker documentation has a [Compose and Rails](https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/) example that shows the basic principles involved.  Of note, you can reuse the [Docker Hub postgres image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) with its prebuilt initialization logic rather than trying to build your own.

Comment: And you can probably use official base images for either, no need to build your own from apt packages.

Comment: @Thilo, Thanks very much for your help. Now I have 4 Images - PostgreSQL, tomcat, OpenJDK, ubuntu. out of which ubuntu and open JDK are directly from the hub.
My question is when needed tomcat, I only had FROM openjdk:8-jdk in my tomcat Docker file. But when I needed Postgres, FROM ubuntu:16.04 in my Postgres docker file.
Why do I need a container OS for Postgres and not for tomcat/OpenJDK? 
Will I want to keep tomcat, Postgres, OpenJDK in the same container OS?

Comment: You don't need images for Ubuntu and OpenJDK.  Just an image with Postgres and one with Tomcat. One image for each application. Both available from Docker hub: https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/ https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/  Then follow the installaton instructions for these images as to how to set up your database (for postgres) and how to deploy your war file (for tomcat).

Answer (score -2):

Try this maybe work. Edit the compose file like this:

```
.
.
.
EXPOSE 8080
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh
CMD ["/usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh", "run"]
.
.
.
```